# Making a GET request with a custom BODY using Axios

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I'm trying to make a get request with a custom body using Axios. The request is made from my frontend (`React`) to my backend (`Node`). Every time I received a `404 error` because my backend does not receive data, and I wonder why? I read the Axios documentation again and again, but I missing something, or what is it happening?
Please help.

This is my code

```
function Test_file() {
    const [list, setList] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        let config = {
            method: 'get',
            url: "http://localhost:8080/theUsers",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            data: {
                "queryData": {
                    "user": "theUser"
                }
            }

        }
        const fetchData = async (config) => {
            try {
                let response = await axios(config)
                console.log(response)
                setList(response.data)
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error.response)
            }
        }
        fetchData(config)
    }, [setList]);


    return (
        <div>
            {list.map((item) => (
                <div key={item.users}>
                    <h3>Account: {item.users}</h3>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}

export default Test_file;
```

Comment: Hey there, can you include more detail about the 404 error? Does the error exist when you don't include the data? 404 usually means that there is no route that exists (e.g., you don't have a backend endpoint with /theUsers).

Comment: When using GET you should go for the params and not data field of the axios object:
params: {
                "queryData": {
                    "user": "theUser"
                }
            }

Also, 404 means that the server wasn't able to find the requested resource, this seems something not related to the data you pass but to the URL itself

Comment: It's weird because I checked the logs in my server and it does not receive any data. So that's why I got a 404 error.

Comment: You have to show us your server router configuration